# Alternatives to memcached / file caching for a very large, mostly static site on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a very large site; the data, from a MySQL database hosted with Amazon RDS, is contained in two tables each with about 20M records, and the total number of pages on the site is about 40M. These pages are mostly static (they are each updated about fortnightly) and mostly do not change with user interaction. I have recently migrated the site to Rails and am testing deploying it on Heroku.

I understand that Heroku denies me access to the file system, which would otherwise be my first choice for a caching solution -- I could cache each of the mostly static 40M pages. Varnish is not available as I am on Cedar. Is memcached a suitable alternative to file system caching for a site of this size? As my database is over 30GB, would I need to purchase memcached space of commensurate size?

If memcached is not appropriate, are there any alternative caching solutions, or alternatives to Heroku altogether, where I could deploy my Rails app but take advantage of file system caching?  All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to look at using a simple VPS instead of Heroku.  Most of these will give you ample disk space thus allowing you to use simple disk caching.

Whilst Heroku will fit most cases, this isn't one that fits well.  You could purchase large amounts of Memcached space, you could also cache rendered pages in your database somehow, but I feel in this instance, you'll save more time and headaches going another route.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. As my database is already with RDS, I guess I should consider going the route of deploying the Rails app to an EC2 instance in order to reduce latency to the database...